# How change DNS alias using C#?

Tags: c#, dns

I have a dns alias with two possible values ​​server1 and server2. 
Current value - server1.
How can I change the value on server2 using .Net (C#)?

Comment: How would you do that without c#?

Comment: Use a configuration file?

Comment: I did it manually, but now it needs to be automated.